# Why does one often have to check in extra early, i.e. 3-4 hours early, before the flight departure for (covid-19) repatriation flights?

Tags: air-travel, check-in, covid-19

I read on https://twitter.com/RichardBarrow/status/1247761807839657984?s=20:

> In addition, for repatriation flights, you often have to check in extra early like 3-4 hours beforehand.

Why does one often have to check in  extra early, i.e. 3-4 hours early, before the flight departure for repatriation flights?

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- [Quora](https://qr.ae/pNr1mX)

Comment: 3-4 hours is not really that early for an international flight, 3 hours is a pretty common recommendation or even requirement these days with extra security everywhere. See for example Delta: https://www.delta.com/us/en/check-in-security/check-in-time-requirements/international-check-in

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106586/discussion-on-question-by-franck-dernoncourt-why-does-one-often-have-to-check-in).

Comment: @PhilippNagel I never saw a check-in being *required* 3 hours before departure. Your Delta link doesn't give any such example. Could you or the comment upvoters please share your knowledge on [What regular, commercial international flight requires a check-in at least 3 hours before departure?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/156634/1810) I'd be curious. Thanks.

Answer (score 46):

The additional check in time is needed for all the extra paperwork.  Repatriation flights are organized and approved by governments to help return citizens to their country of origin.  They can't let anyone on board who is simply willing to pay the fare.  They must check and double check your passport, citizenship status, etc.  Moreover, scheduling a repatriation flight is not the same as regular commercial flight operation.  The planes often arrive empty, without a regular gate to occupy, without a regular slot to fly and the whole operation can be changed at the last-minute.  If you really want to get on the flight then it's best to be there extra early to deal with the unexpected.

Comment: Also, it makes sense that if your country is going through all the hassle of organizing a flight at this moment, to try to ensure that the travellers will not arrive at the last minute. And I guess right now there airports only have minimal staff, so operations are slow (they will not keep the personal needed to service an airplane in 15 minutes just to have them stand idle the rest of the day, they will keep the minimum personal even if that means that the procedure takes longer).

Comment: If you're curious, you can see a bit of footage from a repatriation flight organized by the US government from Kathmandu at https://twitter.com/USAmbNepal/status/1246765484936056832 and it's not the main point of the video but you see a lot of extra desks and steps run by people for whom this isn't their main job and they can process only so many people at a time, so it takes a while to get through everybody.

Comment: "They must check and double checking your passport, citizenship status, etc." aren't airlines doing that whenever someone checks in?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt the airlines are normally checking your passport / Visa with Timatic which is an automated system that works the travel rules out for you. Timatic is not going to give the answer to "can this person get on this repatriation flight".

Comment: Also, repatriation flights are unique. If you miss your regular flight, you can just book the next plane which goes in a few hours (or the next day). If you miss your repatriation flight, there might be no other such flight for the foreseeable future.

Comment: @abligh I don't follow. Presumably you can't book onto a repatriation flight without having a passport of the correct nationality. The standard passport checks will verify that you are the person who owns the passport. What more is needed?

Comment: Do you have any source about any "extra paperwork"? The whole seems more like a way of making sure all get on board.

Comment: @JBentley Then again, I already had the joy to be put through *four* passport controls on a regular flight, including a final one where everybody had to get out of the waiting area at the gate again (and that was really acheck, not the final *presenting* your passport at the gate)

Answer (score 24):

In addition to jcklopp's excellent answer, the other reason they want you there early is that they absolutely do not want you to miss this flight. Repatriation flights are "last chance" flights, and there are two nightmare scenarios that they want to avoid at all costs. One is where they have to delay the flight to wait for someone who hasn't arrived, possibly requiring new permissions from the departure country and possibly endangering the people who actually made it on time. They so dislike this that they probably won't do it, leading to nightmare scenario 2 where someone who should have been evacuated is left behind in a dangerous place. Almost by definition repatriation flights are coming from places where travelling to an airport is going to be more difficult than usual, so aiming to arrive very early gives and extra buffer against being late.

Answer (score 8):

As an employee in an airline that is currently operating many repatriation flights, I can confirm both answers from @jcklopp and @DJClayworth and add one more reason, that is the health briefing.

Repatriation flights related to the COVID-19 situation have very special health precautions and passengers must be briefed in advance before boarding. This includes masks and gloves distribution, seating policy (one seat must be empty between passengers, etc.) and lavatory usage, food distribution and collection. Also, identifying potentially infected passengers.

Most of these temporary precautions must be adhered to once onboard, otherwise, there is no use of them, so passengers will be briefed by the ground staff in advance, which makes the boarding takes a little extra time than usual.